# Could not insert new outlet?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, outlet

I have just recently begun learning about app development, although I am quite fluent in Java, C and Fortran. I want to make a simple iOS app that just prompts the user to input their name, and when they hit a button a label says Hi [insert name]. I believe I'm going about this the right way although every time I try to link the label to my viewcontroller.h file it gives me this error. I hav gone through so many forums online with people saying they fixed it by deleting the derived data, restarting, reinstalling and what not. I have tried all of those numerous times. I've even uninstalled and reinstalled xcode twice. I was wondering if there are any other problems that could be causing this?

It looks very similar to this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try inserting the outlet using traditional way by declaring @property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel; in .h file. And then using the connections inspector to connect the label on storyboard.

Comment: I realize it's pretty much the same problem, but none of the solutions on that post have helped at all, I still get this issue. Also I tried using the traditional way but using the connections inspector I don't get much (im still pretty new as well). I drag the outlet connections of my label to the .h but nothing happens

Comment: I did a "Clean" and "Build" under "Product"! This helped for me!

Answer (score 1):

[image] 1. Close your project.
 2. Delete the DerivedData folder of you project. (project's folder, or inside
        ~/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/(your project)/ ) or somewhere
        else that were setup by you.
 3. restart your project.

> Otherwise make sure Have checked the target when you created your
>   second view controller

[image]

Comment: I've tried this countless times already. And the target for my seconviewcontroller.m is my application, but for the .h it won't let me select a target, is this right?

Comment: Have you done this during the creation of your secondViewController? Make sure do you have xib file for secondViewController?

Comment: this is gonna sound really bad but what is the xib file? Im really new to this kind of programming

Comment: I think you should have done...You ll be asked for create viewcontrollerwith xib file when you create your view controller.Please refer the image i have added. May be it could be the reason

Comment: I just tried, and I have my xib file which looks pretty much like a storyboard file, so do I use this instead of a storyboard? I was able to write @property IBOutlet UILabel *helloLabel; then link my label to that, but still the shortcut won't work

Comment: Can you check with out short cut? Is it working?

Comment: yeah i get a bunch of errors when compiling, and I can't drag my labels onto the code like I should be able to. I write this
@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UILabel *helloLabel;

but still nothing. And for some reason nonatomic, weak and UILabel aren't highlighted in other colours

Comment: Did your second view controller subclasses the UIVIewController?

Comment: I don't think so. I have my storyboard secondviewcontroller custom class set to seconviewcontroller and if I change that to UIViewController it won't even let my try to make a connection from a label

Answer (score 0):

Just try that delete your secondviewcontroller and then recreate it.

Comment: just did, doesn't work

Comment: then once , close your xcode and then again open this project.

Comment: I had same problem , then i tried delete that viewcontroller , closed the project and restart my MAC.